# Where is the initialContext content defined?

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

There's this code in an application I'm working on:

```
lup = (T) this.initialContext.lookup("abc/xyz/loc");
```

But I can't find anywhere where "abc/xyz/loc" content is defined. So that, for instance, I could change it.

Where is that located?

It's a jboss server.

Comment: It would help if you specified the type of `initialContext`, but presumably it's defined _in the server JNDI configuration_.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic I don't know. How do I check that? I'm new to using JNDI/initialContext. This application was developed by someone else.

Comment: It will be defined in a context.xml file somewhere in your application tree.

Comment: @user207421 I could find some context.xml files. But: 1) they did not have the "abc/xyz/loc" entry in there. The content was just two lines: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Context path="/an-app2-path"/>; 2) they are located in a folder outside the app folder. Let's say the app folder is c:\mw\tr\app and these files are in c:\mw\tags\app2\v1 (v2, v3...), having one context.xml for each version, all with that same content.

Comment: Can you share what are you doing with looked up resource(Line of codes after lookup)?. I think the jndi should present in standalone.xml or domain.xml file of your jboss.